# Find all descendants of a parent in sql, including descendants of descendants

Tags: sql

I want to find a table like this:

| Parent | Child |
| --- | --- |
| A | B |
| A | C |
| A | D |
| A | E |
| B | C |
| B | D |

So, the first level under A are nodes B and C. And under B is another level of nodes including C and D, however I also want these nodes included as rows under A.

The available dataset consists out of nodes with their level.

| Node | Level |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 2 |
| C | 3 |
| D | 3 |
| E | 2 |

And all the children below B are the rows until E as B and E have the same level.

Is it possible to create a table as I wanted from the information I have?
I have already looked into stored procedures but I have not used these before so I am a bit lost.

Comment: Hi - it is unclear, to me, what data you have and what the result is that you are trying to achieve but it sounds like you will need to use a recursive query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following self-join query:

```
select D.node Parent, T.node Child
from table_name T join table_name D
on T.level > D.level
order by D.node, T.node
```

If you want to select only one node from the nodes with the same level you may use the `ROW_NUMBER()` function as the following:

```
select D.node Parent, T.node Child
from table_name T join
  (
   select *, 
   row_number() over (partition by level order by node) rn 
   from table_name
  ) D
on T.level > D.level
where D.rn = 1
order by D.node, T.node
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/vYi8nJ76).

Comment: Thank you! I needed to add an additional clause to the where statement to exclude the child nodes under node E. But after that it worked.

Comment: You are welcome, I did'nt noticed that requirment, you may also use the `row_number` function to achieve that like [this query](https://dbfiddle.uk/n9sMXoLD)